# clash of deleted template constructor and user defined conversion operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw, visual-studio-2019

I came around a strange error with MSVC compiler.

Let's say that I have class `Foo`, that must not be constructed from anything but `uint32_t` (copy, move and default = ok).

I also have a class `Bar`, that defines a `Foo` conversion operator.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;

    constexpr Foo(const Foo&) = default;
    constexpr Foo(Foo&&) = default;

    // may be constructed only from uint32
    constexpr Foo(uint32_t word)
    {}

    // This expression is required to
    // prevent construction from types that are
    // not uint32_t or copy or move
    // See 9.5.3 Deleted definitions for an example of
    // this specific use case.
    template <typename T>
    constexpr Foo(T) = delete;

};

struct Bar
{
    constexpr operator Foo () const { return uint32_t(); }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr Foo foo = Bar();

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine with MinGW, but MSVC gives an error:

> main.cpp(27): error C2280: 'Foo::Foo<Bar>(T)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

Is this behavior defined by the standard? Or is it a MSVC bug? Or maybe MinGW does something wrong?

---

The error can be eradicated by declaring the `delete`'d template constructor as `explicit`.

Comment: Can the error not be removed by just not having the deleted template constructor in the first place (just remove that completely).

Comment: @MartinYork `that must not be constructed from anything but uint32_t` - didn't you see this part? Error can be removed by declaring deleted constructor as explicit. But this is not the point of the question. The point is the code does not compile with MSVC while it does with MinGW and Clang. **Does the standard say anything about such situation?**

Comment: This probably covered by [n4849](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf) in section: `7.3.1 Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion` but I can't tease out the language myself.